# Make single column of divs all size of screen

Tags: css

Im trying to improve my css skills and a lot of websites now have this design pattern of a single column with different sections. I'm trying to mimic this behavior with a 'section' css class that will (for now) always be the size of the screen. So the result will be many sections in a single column where each section is the size of the screen. To set one section to the size of the screen I made it position:absolute and set the top/left/bottom/right which works, but how do I scale it to multiple sections?

Comment: This is a bit of a vague story with no code, but if you mean fluid design then have a look here: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understood, but if you're looking to have three columns side by side, what you could do is something like this:

```
div.one, div.two, div.three {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
div.one {
    left:0px;
    width:33%;
}
div.two {
    left:33%;
    width:33%;
}
div.three {
    left:66%;
    width:34%;
}
```

This would create three columns that are absolutely positioned, but have a dynamic width and offset.

Additionally, with CSS you're now able to specify widths and heights dependent on the side of the viewport. What you could also do is this:

```
div.one, div.two, div.three {
    display:inline-block; /* multiple divs on one line! */
    height:100vh; /* 100% of the height of the viewport */
    width: 33.3vw; /* 33% of the width of the viewport */
}
```

This would create three `<div>`s which have a resolution of 100% of the viewport and 33% of its width. As the viewport (essentially here, the browser document window) would scale, the elements would resize automatically. This used to be accomplished using Javascript, but CSS3 specifications introduced the units of `vh` and `vw`, and they are now supported by most browsers. I have this demonstrated in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m63xypg9/).

**EDIT:** What you were asking for, I only got about half right. Rather than columns of 33% width, you wanted rows of 33% height. I'm leaving what I originally have because it explains how to use the units, but I'm including this from the comments we made.

Because you aren't able to use `height:33%;` when it comes to sizing based on the height of the document, you actually want to just reverse the units as specified. Using the units I described above, the way to make three rows of 33% height is as follows:

```
div.one, div.two, div.three {
    display:inline-block; /* multiple divs on one line! */
    height:33.3vh; /* 33.3% of the height of the viewport */
    width: 100vw; /* 100% of the width of the viewport */
}
```

This is demonstrated in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m63xypg9/1/).

Comment: I want the opposite effect, one column with three divs below one another. In addition, each div should be the size of the screen.

Comment: Ah i havent seen vh/vw before, I'll give that a try

Comment: I hadn't seen it until the other day myself, and now I'm incredibly giddy to try it out for myself. I think using `vh` here would actually be the solution if you're looking for what I have in the second JSFiddle, since you aren't able to use `height:33%` on a body/html element.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you need to use the `box-sizing` property.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will allow the `section` to touch the full width of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish something like this with jQuery by placing all sections in a common class. Then you would establish the height of the highest section and set each section to that height.

Example sections:

```
    <div class="col" style="background-color: red; float: left; height: 100px;">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color: blue; float: left; height: 300px;">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color: green; float: left; height: 800px;">
       test
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
      $(".col").each(function() {
           maxHeight = 0;
           if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $(this).height();
           }
      });
      if (maxHeight > 0) {
           $(".col").each(function() {
                $(this).css("height", maxHeight);
           });
      }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the width to fill the window. You can do something like this:

```css
.section {
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">this is a section</div>
```

Should be all your really need. To be able to see it you need to change the background color, etc. But you probably know how to do that.

Comment: This code does not do anything; divs are already 100% width by default.